# Convert a context.xml from Tomcat to Jetty

Tags: tomcat, jetty

i have the following context.xml in webapp/META-INF/.
This one is used by tomcat to define value that will be understand by Spring with a Property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>     
<Parameter name="si.host" value="super.com"  override="false"/>   
</Context>
```

Right now im trying to deploy the webapp with the maven jetty plugin :

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.26</version>
    <configuration>
      <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
          <port>8080</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        </connector>
      </connectors>
      <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}\src\test\resources\server\jetty\jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
      <jettyConfig>${basedir}\src\test\resources\server\jetty\jetty.xml</jettyConfig > 
       <contextPath>/myapp</contextPath>
      <webApp>target/myapp.war</webApp>
      <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
      <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>start-jetty</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <daemon>true</daemon>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stop-jetty</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>        
  </plugin>
```

***How can i add this parameter in a jetty.xml file ?***
I have already dig into their documentation and here and on google but found  nothing clear.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thank you ***DogBane*** !!

I have found an other solution without need to modify web.xml
Use the Default web.xml file.

This file is applied to a Web application before it's own WEB_INF/web.xml file

I prefer this than using jetty.xml because it is less verbose.

Just add in the maven plugin configuration section the webDefaultXml with the path to the file below :

```
<web-app
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns   /javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   metadata-complete="true"
   version="2.5">

  <description>
    Default web.xml file.
    This file is applied to a Web application before it's own WEB_INF/web.xml file
  </description>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>si.host</param-name>
      <param-value>super.com</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: `context-param` is ignored in my case. I'm using Jetty 9.

Answer (score 7):

This needs to go in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` which is web-server independent i.e. it will work in both tomcat and jetty:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>si.host</param-name>
  <param-value>super.com</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or you can set it in your jetty xml like this:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  ...
  <Set name="initParams">
    <Map>
      <Entry>
        <Item>si.host</Item>
        <Item>super.com</Item>
      </Entry>
    </Map>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make available outsite this ? because the webapp is deployed not only on jetty but in tomcat with cargo. And if i define this one in web.xml and in context.xml and it is deployed in a tomcat which value is used ?

Comment: You should remove it from context.xml and only keep it in your web.xml.